# receiver operating characteristic (ROC) on a test set

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

The following image definitely makes sense to me. [image]

Say you have a few trained binary classifiers A, B (B not much better than random guessing etc. ...) and a test set composed of n test samples to go with all those classifiers.  Since Precision and Recall are computed for all n samples, those dots corresponding to classifiers make sense.

Now sometimes people talk about ROC curves and I understand that precision is expressed as a function of recall or simply plotted Precision(Recall).

I don't understand where does this variability come from, since you have a fixed number of test samples. Do you just pick some subsets of the test set and find precision and recall in order to plot them and hence many discrete values (or an interpolated line) ?

Comment: This might be a good question to ask on http://stats.stackexchange.com -- they're more focused on statistics and such there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ROC curve is well-defined for a binary classifier that expresses its output as a "score." The score can be, for example, the probability of being in the positive class, or it could also be the probability difference (or even the log-odds ratio) between probability distributions over each of the two possible outcomes.

The curve is obtained by setting the decision threshold for this score at different levels and measuring the true-positive and false-positive rates, given that threshold.

There's a good example of this process in [Wikipedia's "Receiver Operating Characteristic" page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic):

> For example, imagine that the blood protein levels in diseased people and healthy people are normally distributed with means of 2 g/dL and 1 g/dL respectively. A medical test might measure the level of a certain protein in a blood sample and classify any number above a certain threshold as indicating disease. The experimenter can adjust the threshold (black vertical line in the figure), which will in turn change the false positive rate. Increasing the threshold would result in fewer false positives (and more false negatives), corresponding to a leftward movement on the curve. The actual shape of the curve is determined by how much overlap the two distributions have.

If code speaks more clearly to you, here's the code in scikit-learn that [computes an ROC curve](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0650d5502e01e6b4245ce99729fc8e7a71aacff3/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py#L416) given a set of predictions for each item in a dataset. The fundamental operation seems to be ([direct link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0650d5502e01e6b4245ce99729fc8e7a71aacff3/sklearn/metrics/ranking.py#L311)):

```
desc_score_indices = np.argsort(y_score, kind="mergesort")[::-1]
y_score = y_score[desc_score_indices]
y_true = y_true[desc_score_indices]

# accumulate the true positives with decreasing threshold
tps = y_true.cumsum()
fps = 1 + list(range(len(y_true))) - tps
return fps, tps, y_score
```

(I've omitted a bunch of code in there that deals with (common) cases of having weighted samples and when the classifier gives near-identical scores to multiple samples.) Basically the true labels are sorted in descending order by the score assigned to them by the classifier, and then their cumulative sum is computed, giving the true positive rate as a function of the score assigned by the classifier.

And here's an example showing how this gets used: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

Comment: "The curve is obtained by setting the decision threshold for this score at different levels and measuring the true-positive and false-positive rates, given that threshold"  that means a fully parametrised classifier does not have ROC curve, but a single point on the ROC made of coordinates (precision, 1-recall). This implies that only algorithms that map the features into a class memebership degree have ROC curves right ?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding of it.

Comment: Just as a mental exercise, say the classifier is fixed and the threshold is in place (e.g. svm), if you start exploring your test set in small distinct chunks with such a hypothesis, and plot (precision, 1-recall) points each time... I wonder ... should it resemble a discrete ROC curve :D

Comment: Yes, I think what you're saying could be done, in terms of estimating the P/R values from test-set subsamples; I just don't think it's actually done that way very often. But it seems to me a bit like bootstrapping for confidence estimation. You might get more insight by asking on http://stats.stackexchange.com about this.

Answer (score 0):

ROC curve just shows "How much sensitivity you will obtain if you increase FPR by some amount". Tradeoff between TPR and FPR.  Variability comes from varying some parameter of classifier (For logistic regression case below - it is threshold value).

For example logistic regression gives you probability that object belongs to positive class (values in [0..1]), but it's just probability. It's not a class. So in general case you have to specify threshold for probability, above which you will classify object as positive. You can learn logistic regression, obtain from it probabilities of positive class for each object of your set, and then you just vary this threshold parameter, with some step from 0 to 1, by thresholding your probabilities (computed on previous step) with this threshold you will get class labels for every object, and compute TPR and FPR from this labels. Thus you will get TPR and FPR for every threshold. You can mark them on plot and eventually, after you compute (TPR,FPR) pairs for all thresholds - draw a line through them.

Also for linear binary classifiers you can think about this varying process as a process of choosing distance between decision line and positive (or negative, if you want) class cluster. If you move decision line far from positive class - you will classify more objects as a positive (because you increased positive class space), and at the same time you increased FPR by some value (because space of negative class decreased).